# complement vs adjunct

Tags: complements, adjuncts

> “Funny, isn’t it,” she said, “how the law can have a soft spot like
>   that? No, someone had seen her in the village at the time Robin went
>   missing, so she wasn’t really a suspect. It was decided that because
>   of her. . . because she was . . . well, not to put too fine a point on
>   it, that Meg was best (1) **left** out of things entirely, and that’s how
>   it was done.”
>
> “So it was Dieter who found the body then.” “Yes. He told me about it
>   that same evening. He was still in shock – hardly making sense: all
>   about how he had come (2) **racing** down from Gibbet Wood, yelling
>   himself hoarse . . . leaping fences, sliding in the mud . . . running
>   into the yard, looking up at the empty windows. Like dead eyes, they
>   were, he kept saying, like the windows of the Brontes’ parsonage. But
>   as I said, poor Dieter was in shock. He didn’t know what he was
>   saying.” (The Weed that Strings the Hangman’s Bag)

I guess the first participial construction is a complement of the adjective *best*, while the second participial construction is an adjunct for it’s not necessary to complete the meaning. Am I right?

Comment: That sounds right to me if I'm understanding your question. Isn't racing used as an adverbial adjunct in **(2)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (1) is, formally, a simple passive construction *Meg was left out of things*, with *best* as an adverb modifying the clause. It has, however, idiomatic force: the construction *X is best VERBed* means *The best thing to do is to VERB X*. In this case, “It was decided that the best thing to do was to leave Meg out of things.”

Your (2) is a participial phrase, like the following participial phrases headed by *yelling, leaping, sliding, looking*. In traditional grammar they would be parsed as adjuncts modifying *come*; functionally, however, it makes more sense to treat *come* as a [*copula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28linguistics%29) which takes these phrases as *subject complements* –that is, they are attributed to the subject *he*.